# Object order creation QT for C++ and QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm developing an application in Qt/QML in a Linux environment. As the application grown bigger several issues appeared.

A particular issue is related to a C++ object`translator` referred inside the QML sources. The project builds correctly and the `translator` object works for almost all the items in QML. However, in some places, I get the wrong text. Consider the following example:

```
Text{
    x: 1036; y: 108
    id: incomingLabel
    text: qsTr("Weather") + translator.tr;  // referred object
    color: "white";
    font.pixelSize: 34
}
```

In the case I got `"WeatherUndefined"` as text, all appended. My guess is that when this QML text element requires the text attribute, the `translator` object is not yet created and that causes the `tr` to be `undefined`.

This is how I register the C++ class in QML:

```
Translator translator(app.data(),":/translations");
viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("translator", &translator);
```

It should be noted that the problem does not appear on Windows but only in my Linux environment.

The complete code for the translator class is:

```
Yes translator.tr is a read only property. The translator code is:

#include "translator.h"

#include <QDebug>

Translator::Translator(QApplication *app, const QString &source, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    m_app(app),
    m_source(source)
{
    addTranslation("DE", "lang_de_DE.qm");
    addTranslation("ES", "lang_es_ES.qm");
    addTranslation("FR", "lang_fr_FR.qm");
    addTranslation("IT", "lang_it_IT.qm");
}

void Translator::addTranslation(const QString &name, const QString &file)
{
    if (!m_translations.contains(name))
        m_translations.insert(name, file);
}

QString Translator::tr()
{
    return "";
}

void Translator::setSource(const QString &source)
{
    m_source = source;
}

void Translator::translate(const QString &language)
{
    if (language == "EN")
        removeTranslation();
    if (m_translations.contains(language))
    {
        QString langURL = m_translations.value(language).toString();
        if (m_qtTranslator.load(langURL, m_source))
        {
            removeTranslation();
            m_app->installTranslator(&m_qtTranslator);
            emit languageChanged();
        }
    }
}

void Translator::removeTranslation()
{
    m_app->removeTranslator(&m_qtTranslator);
    emit languageChanged();
}
```

> The header file:

```
#ifndef TRANSLATOR_H
#define TRANSLATOR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QTranslator>

class Translator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString tr READ tr NOTIFY languageChanged)

    public:
        explicit Translator(QApplication *app, const QString &source, QObject *parent     = 0);

    void addTranslation(const QString &name, const QString &file);
    void setSource(const QString &source);

    Q_INVOKABLE void translate(const QString &language);

    QString tr();

signals:
    void languageChanged();

private:
    QApplication *m_app;
    QString m_source;
    QVariantMap m_translations;
    QTranslator m_qtTranslator;
    void removeTranslation();
};

#endif // TRANSLATOR_H
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In this case I would make the `translator` object as a singleton

Comment: Is `Translator.tr` read only property?

Comment: The problem is in `Translator` or at least is related to `Translator` w.r.t. the  linux distro used. Once a context property is registered, that's it, it should work, always. If you want to be really helped just show us the `Translator` class.

Comment: I updated the code above

Comment: Are you sure that the default fallback for the translation is picked-up? It could be that the translator messes up with not translated text,  which explains why you didn't see the problem everywhere.  Please provide also the header...

Comment: I updated with the header. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether the problem lies in `translator` or `tr`.

If `translator` is not created yet,  you will get this error in the console:

> ReferenceError: translator is not defined.

And you won't see `Weatherundefined` in your Text object.

If `translator` exists but not `tr`, then `translator.tr` will return `undefined`, so you will get this output when calling `qsTr("Weather") + translator.tr`:

> Weatherundefined

I suggest you call some console.log() to pinpoint the problem:

```
Text{
    x: 1036; y: 108
    id: incomingLabel
    text: {
       console.log(translator);
       console.log(translator.tr);
       return qsTr("Weather") + translator.tr();  // referred object
    }
    color: "white";
    font.pixelSize: 34
}
```

Also I notice that your translator object is allocated on stack, that could cause problem too.

Comment: I tried with allocating the object in the heap, still not working

Comment: @RamsésRamírez, what's the output of `console.log(translator)`?

Comment: @RamsésRamírez, I mean when you get `Weatherundefined`, what's the output of `console.log(translator)`?

Comment: It's kind of hard to see the debug 'cause my target is a development board and for some reason wehn i add: 
console.log(translator);
console.log(translator.tr);
The text appears to be empty, however, I tested it on a windows machine and i get:
qml: Translator(0x28fdc0)
qml: